# Will tuple unpacking be directly supported in parameter lists in Scala?

Tags: scala, parameters, tuples, iterable-unpacking

In Haskell you can write:

```
x :: (Int,Int) -> Int
x (p,s) = p
```

In Scala you would write:

```
def x(a: (Int, Int)) = a._1
```

or:

```
def x(a: (Int, Int)) = a match {
    case (p, s) => p
}
```

Why not have something like

```
def x(_: (p: Int, s: Int)) = p
```

or

```
def x(foo: (p @ Int, s @ Int)) = p
```

?

Comment: That kind of pattern matching wouldn't very useful if you can have only *one* method definiton. You would need multiple definitions like in Haskell to make it *really* useful, and this would change the structure of the language considerably.

Comment: To clarify @Landei's comment, Haskell doesn't allow multiple definitions of a function.  It just has nice sugar for pattern matching.  In Scala terms it's as if you could write "def f[A](Some(p : A), alt : A) = p;def f(None, alt : A) = alt" instead of "def f(x : Option[A], alt : A) = x match { case Some(p) => p; case None => alt}".   Unfortunately, Scala has Java style overloading and does algebraic data types through subtyping, both of which create ambiguity.

Comment: @James Iry: Yes, I know technically the "multiple definitions" in Haskell are only hidden `case ... of` statements. But from a user's point of view this is only an implementation detail.

Comment: @Landei The translation into case expressions is an implementation detail.  But the concept that they aren't multiple definitions is not an implementation detail. It's in the user's face given that f only has one type and all the patterns for f must agree with the one type of f.

Comment: @James Iry: Although I think it is clear from the context that we're not talking about overloaded functions, I agree calling it "multiple definitions" is sloppy. But what would be a better term? Something like "pattern match based dispatch"? But that sounds ridiculous.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called *destructuring* and, in it's general form, would go well beyond just tuple unpacking.  I've often found myself wishing that Scala had it since it's such a natural extension of the pattern matching syntax:

```
def first((f: Int, l: Int)) = f
def displayName(Person(first, last)) = last + ", " + first
```

Destructuring *is* (sort of) present in the form of variable/value definitions:

```
val (f, l) = tuple
val Person(first, last) = person
```

Unfortunately, there are some [type](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/8344) [safety](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-140) [issues](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4670) around such definitions that I think make it unlikely that you'll see destructuring in parameter lists any time soon.

Comment: Thanks for all your answers. Daniel's answer is right as well but I've chosen this one as it contains useful web references to understand a bit more of the technical details. Thanks again to all!

Comment: nice one, +1 from me--destructuring requires a predicate line of code, but still far easier to look at than myTuple._0, etc.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a function that receives an argument list which corresponds to the types of the Tuple, apply `Function.tupled` to that function and then apply the tuple:

```
scala> def fun(x:Int,y:Int)=x+y
fun: (x: Int,y: Int)Int

scala> val tuple = (1,2)
tuple: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

scala> Function.tupled(fun _)(tuple)
res9: Int = 3
```

This way you achieve a valid workaround for your problem

Comment: Ok, you're right regarding the simple case I gave as an example, but what about more complex parameters like: list.foldLeft((0,0))((a: (Int, Int), x: Int) => ... a._1...) Here I can't just change the function definition.

Comment: You could, using function currying, apply `tupled` the parameters of certain parts of the function. However, it would always be more complicated than using intermediary variables such as `val (a,b) = tuple`. I must say, nevertheless, I do not dislike tuple._1 or tuple._2

Answer (score 2):

That's called multiple dispatch, and it is not supported by JVM. Scala *could* rewrite a method to make the explicit match unnecessary, though, but it is not a priority -- or, as far as I know, even planned -- to do so.

Interestingly, it is supported for functions, in a sense, with the restriction that all variants must appear together. For example:

```
def x: ((Int, Int)) => Int = {
    case (p, _) => p
}
```

Comment: Not multiple dispatch.  Haskell doesn't even have single dynamic dispatch.

Comment: @James I believe you know what you are talking about, but it certainly does look to me that it chooses the definition to be applied based on the run-time value of the parameters, which is the very definition of multiple dispatch. So what's the difference?

Comment: If you look at his examples again there's no dispatch - he's not trying to dynamically choose different methods.  All that he's doing is pulling apart a tuple into named variables.  He just happens to use the name "x" in several different ways to give examples of possible sugar Scala could put on destructuring method arguments.

Comment: @James Well, yes, but I assumed that was just a simplification of his actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to make parameter lists and tuples the same thing in the language.

Comment: I recall Martin Odersky saying that parameter lists and tuples may be unified in a future version of Scala.

Comment: Yes, he has mentioned it. I wouldn't hold my breath though, there are some pretty tricky compatibility issues with method overloading.