# Scala: Unpacking tuple as part of argument list

Tags: scala, tuples, iterable-unpacking, arity

I am trying to send the result of a method call's tuple, as **part** of the argument list for another method.

Target method

```
def printResult(title: String, result: Int, startTime: Long, endTime: Long)
```

Return from method, partial argument list

```
def sendAndReceive(send: Array[Byte]): (Int, Long, Long)
```

---

In other words, I am trying to call `printResult(String, (Int, Long, Long))`. If the method return signature matches the method call, then I could have used

```
(printResult _).tupled(sendAndReceive(heartbeat))
```

This results in syntax error

```
printresult("Hi", Function.tupled(sendAndReceive(heartbeat))
```

### Workaround

I am resorting to manually unpacking the tuple, then using it when calling the method

```
val tuple = sendAndReceive(heartbeat)
printResult("Heartbeat only", tuple._1, tuple._2, tuple._3)
```

Is there a more elegant way to unpack and send a tuple as part of argument list?

### References

[Scala: Decomposing tuples in function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615656/scala-decomposing-tuples-in-function-arguments)

[Invoke a method using a tuple as the parameter list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322436/invoke-a-method-using-a-tuple-as-the-parameter-list)

[Will tuple unpacking be directly supported in parameter lists in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399824/will-tuple-unpacking-be-directly-supported-in-parameter-lists-in-scala)

[Tuple Unpacking in Map Operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905207/tuple-unpacking-in-map-operations)

Answer (score 23):

You can do the following:

```
val (result, startTime, endTime) = sendAndReceive(heartbeat)
printResult("Heartbeat only", result, startTime, endTime)
```

Comment: Thanks, I agree this works. But can I do it without unpacking the tuple?

Comment: Well that's a different question to the one you aksed originally: "more elegant way to unpack". :-) Now you want to do it without unpacking.

Comment: I don't think I express the question clear enough :) I upvoted though. I want to do something like `invokeMethod(arg1, arg2, tuple)`

Comment: Of course, if you can you change or overload the method signature of def printResult(title: String, result: Int, startTime: Long, endTime: Long) to def printResult(title: String, t: [Int, Long, Long]) you don't have to unpack the tuple before you call printResult.

Answer (score 5):

Are you attached to this function signature?

```
def printResult(title: String, result: Int, startTime: Long, endTime: Long)
```

If it is your code and you can modify it, then you can try and use currying instead like this:

```
def printResult(title: String)(result: Int, startTime: Long, endTime: Long)
```

Then you can execute it like this:

```
printResult("Curried functions!") _ tupled(sendAndReceive(heartbeat))
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach involves case classes for the tuple, for instance like this,

```
case class Result(result: Int, startTime: Long, endTime: Long) {
  override def toString() = s"$result ($startTime to $endTime)"
}

def sendAndReceive(send: Array[Byte]): Result = {
  // body
  Result(1,2,3)
}

def printResult(title: String, res: Result) = println(title + res)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, case class and type definitions are possible. I am looking for something concise and expressive. E.g. Python's kwargs

Comment: @hanxue kwargs approach may work assuming all elements in the tuple belong to the same type; yet consider the type for (1,2,3).productIterator is Iterator[Any] although a priory we know all elements are Int.

Answer (score 1):

This can indeed be achieved without unpacking the tuple using [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) (and tupling the function as you did):

```
import shapeless.syntax.std.tuple._

(printResult _).tupled("Hi" +: sendAndReceive(???))
```

`"Hi" +: sendAndReceive(???)` just prepends the value `"Hi"` to the tuple returned by `sendAndReceive`.